# UITableView header UITableViewAutomaticDimension not working

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want to make my tableview header have automatic height because I have label in my header view that can have multi line text.
I've set following steps:

in view did load ad

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 200
}
```

But it still not working.
Here is my storyboard configuration (I have set lines to 0 and line break to word wrap.

Another question: Is the custom view I added on the top of TableViewCell is a header cell?

[image: Here is my storyboard configuration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ended up using method to calculate height for label and added the height to the View.

```
private func heightForView(text: String, font: UIFont, width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        label.font = font
        label.text = text
        label.sizeToFit()

        return label.frame.height
}
```

In the viewDidLoad()

```
let labelHeight = heightForView(text: post.content, font: contentLabel.font, width: contentLabel.frame.width)
headerView.frame.size.height = headerView.frame.size.height + labelHeight
```

Still curious why the `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` not working in this case.